# VS 2013 browserLink is undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2013, browser-link

In the `browserLink` JavaScript file, an exception is being thrown here:

```
if (head.length > 0 && browserLink.sourceMapping.canMapToSource(head[0]))
```

The exception is:

> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of
>   the property 'canMapToSource': object is null or undefined

This is because the `browserLink` object is undefined.  Has anyone experienced this issue with VS 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to resolve my issue.  This old site uses framesets, so I looked at my doctype declaration and noticed that it was using Transitional.  I fixed this by changing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

...to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
```

The Javascript error has stopped occurring.  It seems that VS 2013 expects your pages to use the proper doctype which I agree that it should.  I can't guarantee that this will solve everyone's problem, but it solved mine.